# How to solve this limit? (Without L'Hôpital's rule)

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I only know that it should be something with $\,e\,$ but I don’t have and idea how to solve it.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^n-(n+2)^n}{(n+2)^n-(n+3)^n}$$

Comment: The limit should be $1/e$.

Comment: Divide the numerator and the denominator by $(n+2)^n.$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Why do you ask without Hopital's Rule?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write as $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }\dfrac{\big[(n+1)/(n+2)\big]^n-1}{1-\big[(n+3)/(n+2)\big]^n}\;$.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is
$\;\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^n=e\,$.

From this you can get
$\;\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{2}{n}\right)^n\,$ and
$\;\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{3}{n}\right)^n\;$ which will get you the result.